# How To Roll Back DR Transactions Without Breaking Mirror

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring, disaster-recovery

We have a full data center DR test coming up and will need to fail over all of our SQL Server databases to the DR site.  The majority (>80%) of our databases are SQL Server 2008 R2 using Database Mirroring for DR.  The test duration is 56 hours.  We have requirements to

1. maintain production availability during the test,
2. roll back any changes made during the test and
3. resume normal operations (including re-establishing mirroring) within the time window allowed for the test.

The biggest issue we have is that we will need to break the mirror to allow both production and DR to be available for read/write.  That forces us to take backups and copy them to DR to resume mirroring.

There are ~2,000 databases involved with over 4 TB of backup files.  At those volumes it would not be possible to resume mirroring within the time frame allowed.

Does anyone have any ideas or know of any third-party software that would meet the requirements set down for this test?

I know Oracle has a Flashback feature which allows administrators to manually set a recovery point and roll back to that point when ready.  Is there anything in SQL Server that could let us do that?

Comment: Are you using enterprise edition ? What mode is mirroring running on ?

Comment: No there isn't anything like the flashback feature, Would it be sufficient to create snapshots of the databases and do testing on those? Can you make snapshots on the SAN level, or virtual machines

Comment: @Kin:  We're using Enterprise Edition.  We may have to try frame-based replication if we can't come up with a native DBMS means of doing it.